# Setting user agent of WebView custom renderer make Navigated event fire twice on Xamarin Forms Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to set a custom User Agent string on a Xamarin Forms WebView on iOS and Android.  I am using a custom renderer for this on both platforms.  The iOS version works fine, but on Android, the following code when placed in the OnElementChanged of the Android custom renderer causes the Navigated event of the WebView to fire twice, once when the WebView starts to load and once when it is actually completed.  Commenting out the setting of the user agent causes the Navigated event to only fire once when the load is complete like it should.  Is there another way to set the user agent on Android or is there some other way to get around what seems to be a bug here?

```
// get useragent
var userAgent = this.Control.Settings.UserAgentString;
if (!userAgent.Contains("MyApp"))
{
    userAgent += " MyApp";
    // set useragent
    this.Control.Settings.UserAgentString = userAgent;
}
```

Comment: By `fire twice`, why don't you set a variable to control it to achieve your goal? Will it go wrong way?

Comment: I thought about that, but that seems like a very ugly hack.  What if this "bug" was fixed in the future?  Then it would suddenly break possibly without notice.

Comment: @jpcoder Have you ever found a fix for that?